# How to use a date in Python variable with a SQL query in pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, sqlalchemy, pyodbc

I have a python code which looks like this( snippets)
.....

```py
lastCheckTime = datetime.datetime.strptime(strDate, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")

connection_url = URL.create("mssql+pyodbc", query={"odbc_connect": connection_string})


engine = create_engine(connection_url)


sqldf = pd.read_sql_query(
    """\
SELECT * from ABC, XYZ, LMN, PQR 
WHERE ABC.id = XYZ.id 
  AND XYZ.TO_CLASS != '827' 
ORDER BY ABC.creation_date desc
    """, 
    engine,
)
```

This works fine but I want to execute the query with a check for date ABC.creation_date > lastCheckTime.

Unable to figure out how to execute this query.

The original query was in oracle . Please see below how it looks.
What should be the equivalent of `to_char(ABC.creation_date) > :lastCheckTime` in my query

```sql
SELECT * from ABC, XYZ, LMN, PQR 
WHERE ABC.id = XYZ.id 
  AND XYZ.TO_CLASS != '827'
  AND to_char(ABC.creation_date) > :lastCheckTime  
ORDER BY PCREATION_DATE desc
```

Comment: You can use the `params=` argument to pass parameter values to [read_sql_query()](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_sql_query.html)

Comment: Thank you @GordThompson. There were lots of misleading posts on stackoverflow on how to pass params using :name or %s etc  but finally found the solution on how to do it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The query should be as follows for it to work, use ? as placeholder and name the variable in params

sqldf = pd.read_sql_query("SELECT * from ABC, XYZ, LMN, PQR WHERE ABC.id = XYZ.id AND XYZ.TO_CLASS != '827'AND ABC.creation_date > ***?*** ORDER BY ABC.creation_date desc", ***engine,params={lastCheckTime}***)